# Cordova Google-Analytics-Plugin Missing Exec

Tags: javascript, cordova, google-analytics

I'm implementing [Dan Wilson's Google-Analytics-Plugin](https://github.com/danwilson/google-analytics-plugin) into my Cordova/Ionic application and am getting an odd error. I installed the latest version (1.8.2) of the plugin and implemented it into my app.js:

```
if (typeof window.ga !== "undefined") {
    window.ga.startTrackerWithId('UA-84899403-18');
    window.ga.trackView('Home');
}
```

The condition passes and the code is run, but the console output looks like this:

[image: console output]

There isn't any data in my Google Analytics App Overview but I know it can take a while for that to come in. I've never seen this `missing exc:` and it isn't an error so I can't tell if the plugin is working or not. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a Ripple Emulator issue with the lack of ability to use native Java/Swift code, hence the `missing exec:`. In order to fix or properly test the app with the plugin you need to install it in a better emulator or on a device.